# How to make storage and directory listing without page loading

Tags: php, ajax

Good Day. I am trying to make directories and files listing like this:
[image]

Using PHP and AJAX. Can anyone give me the logic how it works. Or give me site that I can read about this. I think this not require database.

Comment: I need this too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what we need:
https://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php

[image]

File Browser....